# npm view not returning data from nexus

Tags: node.js, npm

Is there a reason to

> npm view "module_name"

to return nothing? No error, no value

I published a module in a private registry (Nexus) from the server

> npm publish --tag develop

and then in my machine I am getting the empty result querying the module. There is no returning error. There is mispelling error in the name.

npm: '6.4.1'
node: '10.14.1'
Nexus: '3.15'